# Is it possible to make text box vertically scrollable when typing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make vertically scrollable html text box which means it automatically triggers to next line when the text box's width is reached while typing(like textarea but not using textarea)?

Comment: You mean an `input type="text"`? It is a strange behavior

Comment: Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why you are not using a text area?

Comment: Text area does not support perfect scrollbar. I want to check perfect scrollbar is work with text box.

Comment: what do you mean  by "perfect scrollbar", what defines perfection here>

Comment: perfect scrollbar is a plugin.

Comment: Please show your markup with code including the plugin reference

Comment: https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar -->  plugin link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Js -> `$('#element').perfectScrollbar();` and html -> `<input type="text" id="element">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have it in this way. CSS with height and overflow as mentioned and contenteditable attribute on div tag to true. Hope it helps.

```
<style>    
 div.textbox {
   background-color: #ececec;
   height: 100px;
   max-height: 100px;
   width: 200px;  
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }
</style>


<div class="textbox" contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut.</div>
```

Comment: Make "text box scrollable" - accepts answer that doesn't use a text box ... hmmm

Answer (score 0):

Simple
Set div height and width and overflow-y equal to scroll

```
div{
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

So when your text reach width of 300px it goes to next line, decrease the height as you want

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to make an `input` of type `text` to have multiline

Answer (score 0):

you can make element editable using this property. it will act as textbox  `contenteditable="true"`

```css
.input {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<p class="input" contenteditable="true">This is a paragraph. It is editable. Try to change this text.This is a paragraph.</p>
```